# "Official" vs "Unofficial" custom ROM from the XDA forums?

Tags: adb, rooting, lineageos

I have a [Lenovo Vibe K5 Plus(a6020a46 3GB RAM variant)](https://www.gsmarena.com/lenovo_vibe_k5_plus-7947.php) which I'd like to root and install a custom ROM on.

On the XDA forum dedicated to [custom ROMS for this device](https://forum.xda-developers.com/f/lenovo-vibe-k5-plus-roms-kernels-recoveries-o.6052/) there is a plethora of options including some marked "Official" and some "Unofficial".

Should I choose the ["Unofficial" build of 'LineageOS'](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/rom-unofficial-8-1-lineageos-15-1-for-vibe-k5-k5-with-sim-management.3962234/), which as I understand is the most popular ROM, so maybe it will have the best community support? Other popular "Unofficial" builds include ['Pixel Experience'](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/rom-10-0-unofficial-pixel-experience-aosp-a6020.4089415/) and ['Orange Fox.'](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/unofficial-recovery-orangefox-recovery-project-a6020-vibe-k5-plus.4198319/)

Or should I choose one of the ["Official" build like that of 'Arrow OS'](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/rom-10-0-official-arrowos-10-0-stable-volte-weekly-a6020.4028183/) though it is not that popular?

Will a more popular but "Unofficial" ROM provide better community and hardware support or will an "Official" ROM build be better in terms of support and stability?

[A related thread I found on XDA forums](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/whats-the-difference-between-an-official-rom-and-an-unofficial-rom.2398582/) talks about the differences in Official and Unofficial ROMs but it is for the same ROM(eg: diferent versions of Paranoid Android). Also the the thread does not address the issue that I have asked about.

I am still quite new to all things Android so please give your valuable suggestions on how I can improve my knowledge and questions posted here.

Comment: that is up to your opinion and can't be answered. personally i prefer the state *'stable'* over *'un/official'*

Comment: Which ROM works better in terms of support and stability depends mainly on the person(s) maintaining it. Official builds usually have the advantage that there is a public GIT repository where all changes are documented and can be checked (and best if there is an automated build process that builds the ROM based on this repo). Unofficial builds are often just the binary image you can install. Hence you have to trust the person blindly what is inside.