# Should I choose a custom ROM with or without GApps?

Tags: rooting, custom-roms, gapps

This may be considered an extension of a [question I recently posted.](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/233677/official-vs-unofficial-custom-rom-from-the-xda-forums)

Does an appstore like F-Droid offer the same variety as the Google Play Store? What if I need a Google app(like the appstore,maps,google app etc.) later on, do I need to do any "Flashing" to separately install them?

Will it be better to use a custom ROM version with Gapps or try to live without Google first?

I did try searching around online but there seems to be nothing substantial.

Please provide your valuable suggestion on how I can improve my questions here since I am still very new to Android-rooting as well as Stack Exchange.

Comment: ROMs with built-in GApps are illegal because of license restrictions of GApps. The common way is to flash a ROM and then if you want also flash the desired OpenGApps package (IMHO the maximum desiderable package is "micro" - everything else can be installed from PlayStore if you really want it; mini, full, and higher are just a waste of space).

Comment: F-Droid only host open-source apps. without google play store (vending) you can still install any apk file from untrusted sources. But apps might not work as expected because google play services (gms) is the core of android providing all APIs most apps rely on. https://github.com/microg/GmsCore/wiki